# FreeBSD vs. Illumos

Tags: unix, freebsd, operating-system, illumos

I am using FreeBSD since some years now for server use and archlinux for desktop.

I really use many features of FreeBSD (ports, zfs, jails, pf, ...) now I read about Illumos an OpenSolaris derivate. OpenSolaris itself aslong as I know isn't getting developed anymore. Solaris belongs to Oracle and Linux misses a lot of things known from unix. The only contra is that FreeBSD has not that big community (don't know why) what is shown to the developement. They are missing some more men power...

So how does it look with Illumos?

Is it the right thing looking for?

Are all FreeBSD features available under Illumos?

How does the Feature look like?

Regards

Comment: You should narrow your question(s) to something clearly answerable. "how does it look", "is it the right thing" are not.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Are all FreeBSD features available under Illumos?*

No, there are FreeBSD features that aren't available under Illumos based OSes, and there are also Illumos based OS features that are not in FreeBSD. I would recommend you to install [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/), [SmartOS](http://smartos.org/), [Illumian](http://www.illumian.org/), [Omnios](http://omnios.omniti.com/) and experiment with the ones closest to your need to make your opinion.